# What should be the Content Search Web Part max per page?

Tags: web-part, search, 2013, deployment, page-layout

I'm currently working on a department site prototype for an Intranet, which is to be packaged up and used to spawn around a dozen sites using the same Web Template.

While trying to convert the design into concept I noticed there are about 7 spots where I can use Content Search Web Parts as opposed to list rollups. As a developer and a designer, I love thinking of using 7 seperate CSWPs on a page since I can pre-configure them in Design Manager and plop them into my page layout, lessening my workload configuring each site spawn. I also like how easy it is to create new Display Templates.

I'm concerned with performance. On a single-server SharePoint installation and the page-layout only loaded with two CSWPs I've had several times where one, the other, or both would fail. I'm wondering what kind of madness would occur with 7 on 12 sites used by several users at once.

Does anyone have any experience or a best practice concerning how many CSWPs are too many on a page?

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of SharePoint the Core Results Web Part ran synchronously.  I saw situations where there were two or more on a page where things could definitely stack up and it would take 20+ seconds to load the page.  My team ended up overriding the out of the box web part to create an asynchronous version; the resulting page load times were a fraction of the previous times.

I've not yet validated, but I would not be surprised if the CSWP is also synchronous out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Search webparts have an option whether they query synchronously (server-side; the default) or asynchronously (client-side). Still, even if you have multiple asynchronously querying webparts, chance is that users will start complaining about too much delayed loading. Therefore, consider also applying the AD group based caching. Cf. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-a-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-0dc16de1-dbe4-462b-babb-bf8338c36c9a

I am still looking for a guideline on how many search webparts one should apply on one page though.